# Dragable divs in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have need to being able to drag a div from one to another. Problem is that what I have considers all inner divs as separate things to drag. My main goal is that if any part of the div gets dragged that it carries the whole thing.

```
 <div ng:controller="controller">
<div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list" class="group item" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div>header {{item}}</div>
    <div>body {{item}}</div>
    <div>footer {{item}}</div>
</div>

<div ui:sortable="sortableOptions" ng:model="list2" class="group dragarea" >
    <li ng:repeat="item in list2" class="item">{{item}}</li>
</div>
```

```
$scope.list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

$scope.list2 = [];

$scope.sortableOptions = {
    update: function(e, ui) {
               },
    receive: function(e, ui) {


    },
    connectWith: ".group"
};
```

You can drag the header,body or footer divs separately which is what I don't want. I want any part of it being dragged to carry all 3 parts of it.

Here is a fiddle with my current work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/cna5L7b7/

Comment: Can you not just wrap the 3 items in their own container div, and let that be the draggable object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your header, body and footer in one div:

```
<div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list" class="group item" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div>
        <div>header {{item}}</div>
        <div>body {{item}}</div>
        <div>footer {{item}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cant believe I didn't see this sooner.